# Как высчитать шанс победы, в случае если у тебя 2 билета на лоторею вместо одного?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

Помогите пожалуйста посчитать шанс, что-то понять не могу. Допустим, в лотерее участвует 1000 билетов, из них 100 билетов выигрышных, значит у тебя шанс выиграть 10%, а что если у тебя 2 билета? Какой шанс, как посчитать?

Comment: Найдите шанс дважды проиграть

Comment: Какая разница, сколько человек участвует?

Comment: @Igor хорошо, давайте перефразируем. Всего есть 1000 билетов

Comment: @MBo шанс проиграть 90% процентов, шанс проиграть дважды опять же непонятно мне как посчитать.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Вы тут какие-то сложные формулы написали. Извните, но оказалось все гораздо проще. Шанс выиграть ~20%. У тебя 2 билета вместо 1го, шанс выиграть становится в 2 раза больше. Конечно, если у тебя будет 10 билетов шанс получается 100%, а на деле 100% гарантии не будет. Но тем не менее, шанс будет довольно близок к 100%. Если у тебя будет 20 билетов — шанс выиграть 200%, то есть как правило должно 2 билета из 20 выиграть.

Comment: Ответ 19% с мелочью, как показано во всех правильных ответах. Если у вас приняли ответ 20%, то... зря вы в том месте учитесь

Comment: Какая жуть и полное непонимание теории вероятностей. Птенцы гнезда ЕГЭшного... :( Мой покойный препод Виктор Саввич, несмотря на хорошее ко мне отношение, меня бы за такое вытолкал с зачета... :( А уж если бы я ему про вероятность 200% понес...

Comment: @Harry ответ MBo выше, вернее чем мой про 19 процентов с копейками. Но шанс 200% значит, что велика вероятность выиграть в лоторее 2 раза.

Comment: @Harry тем не менее я очень благодарен вашим ответам, вы не подумайте. Просто для меня, например, ваш ответ 0.19(009) это что-то совершенно непонятное. Я спрашивал про проценты, а вы какие-то 0.19, еще и в скобочках что-то. Я впервые такое вижу, поймите) И люди, которые будут заходить в этот тред тоже ничего не поймут, если сами не математики.

Comment: В скобочках — это период... Например, 1/3 записывается как 0,3(3)

Answer (score 5):

Как раз вчера малой сдавал модуль по комбинаторике, так что... :)

Итак, всего 1000 билетов. Вытащить из них 2 можно С_1000^2 = 499500 способами.

Вытащить 1 выигрышный — С_100^1*С_900^1 = 90000 способов (один из 100, второй из 900).

Вытащить 2 выигрышных — С_100^2 = 4950 способов (два из 100).

Не вытащить ни одного — С_900^2 = 404550 (два из 900).

Убеждаемся, что сумма вариантов 1, 2, ни одного равна сумме всех вариантов.

Так что вероятность вытащить хотя бы один выигрышный из двух — (90000+4950)/499500 = 0.19(009).

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"

Answer (score 3):

Вероятность, что проиграет один билет - 0.9.

Вероятность, что и второй будет проигрышным, составляет (999-100)/999 = 899/999

Вероятность наступления обоих печальных событий сразу 9/10 * 899/999,  а выигрыша хотя бы одного билета

```
1- 9/10 * 899/999 = 1 - 899/1110 = 211/1110
```

Answer (score 3):

Вероятность вытащить 2 несчастливых билета рассчитывается так.

общее количество исходов вытащить два билета равно `C(2,N)`. Количество исходов, при которых вытаскиваются только несчастливые билеты равно `C(2,M)` где M общее число не выигрышных билетов. Здесь `C` биномиальный коэффициент.

Итого вероятность вытащить 2 проигрышные билета равна на `C(2, M) / C(2, N)` что равно `M *(M - 1) / (N * (N -1))`

Тогда вероятность выиграть хотя бы раз равна `1-M*(M-1)/(N*(N-1))`

Подставлять в эту формулу `M=900, N=1000`, вообще говоря, не совсем верное решение. Правильный ответ очень сильно зависит от того, сколько билетов купили другие участники перед вами. Подстановка `M=900, N=1000` верна лишь в том случае, когда вы являетесь первым покупателям лотерейных билетов.

Если же вы не первый покупатель, то нужно отредактировать m и n так, чтобы они соответствовали покупкам предыдущих участников. Либо же надо писать полную формулу вероятности с возможными исходами для первых покупателей, для чего надо знать сколько билетов купили до вас.

Comment: Мне кажется, что если все покупатели до вас были честными :), то усреднение всех вариантов их покупок все равно приведет к тем же вашим результатам... Доказать теоретически вряд ли сумею — не моя область совершенно, но экспериментально проверить, скажем, при покупке первым, 250-м и последним  — запросто...

Comment: А ведь, кажется, более-менее могу. Представим себе 500 коробок, в которые заранее положили пары билетов из перемешанных случайным образом 1000 билетов. Все. Вы берете одну коробку — и совершенно неважно, когда именно: первым, последним или где-то посредине. Потому что все коробки равнозначны (покупатели честные).

Comment: @Harry да, если мы не знаем результаты предшественников, и нет, если результаты оглашаются сразу. Как и в других задачах по теорверу здесь важны нюансы формулировок.

Comment: Тут согласен — насчет оглашения и формулировок :)